# Change profile for Websphere portal server

Tags: rad, websphere-portal

From my RAD 7, I am trying to create a Websphere portal server (6.1) where i wish to deploy my portlet EAR. Now during creation of the portal server, I get no option to choose a server profile (unlike creation of a websphere app server where it asks you to choose a server profile). When the WPS is created, when i double click it, a profile by the name of wp_profile is already selected and I cannot change it.

How did this profile get created? Also is there a way to change it? When I run profile management tool to create a new profile, that profile is created for WAS and not WPS. So that is not available for selection in the WPS settings page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. The only solution for me was to create a new sever. Then you get the option to choose the profile you want.

Comment: Even when i create new server...it gives me no new option for profile

Answer (score 0):

Using 7.5, with the server stopped I double clicked the server and this had a option to change the profile. Sadly I can't upload pictures yet